# Unable to set Base64 image as background-image MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set a Base64 image get from modal as my body HTML.

So in my `@section` where i render the css i added the following code:

```
@section Css {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/index.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: @Model.bg_color;
            background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,@Model.bg_image);
        }
    </style>
}
```

The image get in `@Model.bg_image` is in the right base64 format as by setting it value in one of online Base64 converter it's generate the right image.

But when the page is load i get the following error instead of get the image shown as my background image:

```
GET data:image/png;base64,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& net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

HTML in  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0z7sbxL/)

EDIT: i've just noticed that the value returned in `Model.bg_image` is different from the one set as base64, like the `+` char is set as `&#x2B;` so the image is not rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Base64 string in your JSFiddle contains HTML-escaped `+` characters:

```
[...] a97WG463tQBFl3MQ00BBNNCK&#x2B;ZxuByOLHB [...]
```

You may want to use the `@Html.Raw()` function to keep ASP.NET from escaping the Base64 string:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,@Html.Raw(Model.bg_image));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert to string, try this;

```
 @{
 string imgSrc = "";
if (Model.bg_image != null)
 {
 var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.bg_image);
 imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
 }
 }

 @section Css {
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/index.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
        background-color: @Model.bg_color;
        background-image: url(@imgSrc);
    }
   </style>
 }
```